# How to implement Python function exec() in C++?

Tags: c++

The `Python` function `exec()` is a very good tool for programming.

For example:

```
/******************************************************
 * we have array names={"ali","hamed"}
 * goal is declare string ali="ali" and hamed="hamed"
 ******************************************************/
```

`Python` code:

```
# used for command
# below line is a syntax python
# in python we dont declare variable
list=["ali","hamed"]  #python syntax
#in python we dont wite {
#python work with tab insteed of {}
for i in list:
    temp = i + ' = "' + i + '"' #temp is a string 
    exec(temp)
```

My question: Is there a similar function exists in C++? If not, how to implement it in C++?

Comment: No, you can't do that in C++, it's a different kind of language. If you wanted to write that function yourself then that's essentially the same as writing a C++ compiler and linker. Not an easy task.

Comment: @ john ok dont exist any other function that help me? or how i can write this code without using exec

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. Instead of saying can C++ do this, or can C++ do that, describe the problem you want to solve. It will be solvable in C++.

Comment: I'm confused about your Python code. The elements of `list` are already strings, so why are you converting them with `str(i)`? What is this supposed to accomplish? Running it in my Python interpreter doesn't illuminate anything.

Comment: @ drewmm  because we want ali="ali"___the exec() delete on "" and run it ____my python is 2.7

Comment: I think your generator line should be `temp = i + ' = "' + i + '"'`, no?

Comment: @  James Kanze ok tankyou for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `exec`, and similar features in other languages (i.e. `eval` in JavaScript) only work because those are *interpreted* languages where variables are defined at *run time*.

You can't do what you're asking in directly C++ because it's a compiled language that requires that all variables and their names are known at *compile time*.

Comment: @unkulunkulu yes, I did.  Suffering from bad cold, drugged up on pseudoephedrine and not typing straight :(

Comment: @ Alnitak this code is python syntax not c++ -i explain how python work in code please read it again

Comment: I already read it.  It only works in Python because it's an _interpreted language_ and the `exec` command allows execution of arbitrary strings.  C++ is _compiled_, so doesn't.

Comment: -ok .but how i can write code above in c++ without using exec?

Comment: @MM-BB by answering john's comment and describing your end goal, not this impossible feature that C++ doesn't have.  Also, look up "XY problem" on Google.

Comment: @MM-BB you have not even remotely clarified the question.  Explain _why_ you think you need to do this.  Think about the whole program you're writing and what problem it is you're attempting to solve.

Comment: no, it's still a useless question.  You've invented an impossible solution to an unknown question.  Ask us the unknown question instead!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it's not trivial, and it will only work on
systems where a C++ compiler is installed.  Basically, C++ is
compiled, so if you want to execute some string which is C++,
you'll have to compile it: write it to a file (probably with
additional boilerplate like some includes), invoke the compiler
(with `system`) to build a DLL, and then load the DLL.

In practice, even if you went to all that effort, you'd probably
find it less useful than you think.  Because C++ requires static
declarations for just about everything, it's much harder to
write small snippets like that and have them usable.  (You 
would, for example, have to wrap it in a function, and generate
`extern` for all of the variables it uses.)  C++ doesn't support
this sort of thing for software engineering reasons; the very
features which make languages like Python so flexible for small,
quickly written programs, cause severe maintenance problems when
used in large scale robust software.  Different languages are
designed for different purposes.  It's very easy to create
a mixed language system using Python for the top level glue
(where you would want a facility such as you describe), and
calling into C++ for the heavy work (where such a facility would
allow the user to trigger core dumps at will).

Alternatively, you can implement a small language in C++.  For
keeping user defined variables, for example, use `std::map`,
rather than declaring the variables.  (That is, after all, what
Python does under the hood.)

Comment: @MM-BB Where does the list come from?  If it's available at compile time, I'd suggest generating the desired C++ as part of the build procedure (using Python!).  If not, you'll end up with a lot of system dependencies; I'd go for the `std::map` solution.

Comment: @MM-BB But explain what you are using it for.  (In my experience, it's not normally the best solution in Python either.  I do a lot of Python, but I've never used `exec` this way.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use strings as parameters,it is NOT a good idea!
you can simply use an id generator function and give an id to every string that you are gonna use ,or if you are using a class you can put that function in the constructor.
no need to that exec() at all!!